# Convert a csv to a multidimension array

Tags: python, arrays, r, matlab, csv

I have a csv containing data as follows:

```
"Store","Dept","Year","Week","Sales"
10,21,2,11,10908
11,30,2,12,12279
11,33,2,13,11061
12,81,2,14,12288
32,70,2,15,9950
```

and would like to obtain a multi-dimension array so that I can easily call:

```
Sales[store, dept, year, week]
```

For example, `Sales[10,21,2,11] = 10908`

Any language is ok. Preferably Python, Matlab, or R.

Somehow I cannot find a solution. I have been struggling to make it work in R, without success so far ([refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654409/r-convert-data-frame-to-multi-dimensional-matrix)). Since I do not care for the language, I am opening the question in a broader sense.

Comment: Are you missing a field in that "Sales[10,21,11] = 10908"? Assuming you are going to provide every field and only fetch the Sales value, you would have a multidimensional sparse array, or a Map of some kind. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Aioros Yes, I corrected the question. And yes, a multi-dimensional sparse array sounds like what I what, although this is new to me so I can only confirm once I see it working.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, this is what you are asking for - python version.  It's not the greatest coding but the basic idea is that the add function recursively populates a dictionary of dictionaries

```
import csv


def add(h, *args):
    """
    >>> add({},1,2,4,8)
    {1: {2: {4: 8}}}
    """
    if len(args) == 2:
        h[args[0]] = args[1]
        return h
    if not(args[0] in h.keys()):
        h[args[0]] = {}
    add(h[args[0]], *args[1:])
    return h


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hoh = {}
    with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        headers = spamreader.next()
        for row in spamreader:
            print ', '.join(row)
            add(hoh, *row)
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(hoh)
```

ps. the reason I've used h and hoh as variable names is that I think of them as "hashes", that's what this type of associative array is known as in perl and awk.  Sorry about that.